# D3 - pie charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have tried many ways but I couldn't draw pie charts in d3 where I have a data like:

```
"something": [{
    "a":"some value",
    "b":"another value",
    .  
    .
    .
},{
    "c":"a value",
    "d":"value",
    .
    .
    .
}]
```

This data is almost 55,000 lines and each group has 19 different value.
Each group starts with "{" and ends with "}". The code I want should draw pie charts dynamically of reading the data.

```
var width = 550;
var height = 350;
var radius = 300/ 2;
var color = d3.scale.category20b();  //builtin range of colors
var svg = d3.select('#pie_chart').append('svg')
                                 .attr('width', width)
                                 .attr('height', height)
                                 .append('g')
                                 .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) +',' + (height / 2) + ')');
var total = 0;

for(var a=0;a<Data.length;a++){
total=total+parseInt(Data[a].count); // simple logic to calculate total of data count value
console.log(total);
}
var pie_data=[];
for( var a=0;a<Data.length;a++){ // simple logic to calculate percentage data for the pie
pie_data[a]=(Data[a].count/total)*100;
}
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius);
// creating arc element.
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.value(function(d,i) { return pie_data[i]; })
.sort(null);
//Given a list of values, it will create an arc data for us
//we must explicitly specify it to access the value of each element in our data array
var path = svg.selectAll('path')
.data(pie(Data))
.enter()
.append('path')
.attr('d', arc)
.attr('fill', function(d, i) {
return Data[i].color;
});
//set the color for each slice to be chosen, from the color defined in sample_data.json
//this creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function
*/
```

2nd try

```
//pie chart

var width = 300;
var height = 300;

  //each arc in the pie chart
  var outerRadius = width/2;
  var innerRadius = width/3;
  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                  .outerRadius(outerRadius);

  //pie chart
  var pie = d3.layout.pie();
  //colors
  var color = d3.scale.category20();

  //Create SVG element
  var svg = d3.select("body")
              .append("svg")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);

//Set up groups
var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
              .data(pie(data))
              .enter()
              .append("g")
              .attr("class", "arc")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")");

//Draw arc paths
arcs.append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(i);
    })
    .attr("d", arc);

//Labels
arcs.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please share your code. You should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MehdiElFadil I destroyed all my code about that part. I didn't want to share something that doesn't work

Comment: @D.Ister actually it is inside the code that doesn't work that the best clues about how to fix it can be found

Comment: @JasonSperske I added them

Comment: @MehdiElFadil I added them

Comment: In your above data are "some value", "another value", etc... numeric values?  What values go into the pie chart?  The sum of each key; "a", "b", "c", etc...  I really don't understand what you are trying to do.  Perhaps add a picture.

Comment: @Mark they are all integer

Comment: So do the keys of a,b,c,etc appear more than once?

Comment: @Mark yes they do, a,b,c etc appear more than once but their integer values are all different. Good question thank you!

Comment: So, last question before I can answer, are you building a single pie chart, where each slice is a, b, c, etc... and the integer values are summed across all your data?  or are you building multiple pie charts, one for each element in your data array?

Comment: @Mark Actually neither, I want to create multiple pie charts where each slice is a,b,c etc. This is a JSON data so, you can think that there are groups starts with { and ends with } for each group I want to create only 1 pie chart but all of them have a,b,c etc so, their slice names will be the same but since they have different integer values they will be different

Comment: @Mark I changed var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg") to var svg = d3.select("#container2").append("svg") and put my data instead your example data and copy the code how it is. Unfortunately, I am not able to see my pie charts instead I see a huge black bar and my datas on top of each other. Do you know why?

Comment: @D.Ister, I can't say what's going wrong without a reproducible example.  Go [here](http://plnkr.co/) and reproduce what you are doing then I'll take a look.

Comment: @Mark can I use something else, this page cannot get my data (it is about 55,000 lines)

Comment: @D.Ister, just cut the data down to something more reasonable.

Comment: @Mark It gave me some trouble sorry for the delay [here it is](http://plnkr.co/edit/vhSlhGpfNKmNcxpe8k2I)

Comment: @D.Ister, your data has non-numeric values in it.  When d3 trys to `pie` and `arc` that it blows up.  *If you check the browser console when debugging*, you would have seen lots of errors.  In this [version](http://plnkr.co/edit/7vzdmj0cYGEYfo2PdEvj?p=preview), I've added a check on the data to screen out non-numeric.  Now your next question is going to be how to fix up those labels....

Comment: @Mark so the problem was basically I have float values but the first piece of code was specifically for integers. Is this right?

Comment: @D.Ister, floats or ints it doesn't matter.  Your problem was the *string* values, those entries with `deepsea` or `E1.1.-.-`

Comment: @Mark Oh okay I got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mark one last question: is it possible me to put the labels out of the pie chart like [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9572040) I tried but I don't want to break the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick example.  It touches on some relatively advanced d3 concepts, so I'll try to explain.

First, let's think about your data.  d3 likes to deal with arrays of object**s**.  You have an array of singular object.  So let's do some data conversion.  You have:

```
[{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3  
}, {
  "d": 4,
  "e": 5
...
```

But what you need is:

```
[
  [{
    "key": "a", 
    "value": 1
   }, {
    "key": "b", 
    "value": 2
   }, {
    "key": "c", 
    "value": 3
   }
  ],[{
    "key": "d", 
    "value": 4
   }
   ....
  ]
]
```

Luckily d3 has an almost builtin function for this, [d3.entries](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_entries).

```
var data = [{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
},{
    "a": 4,
    "d": 5,
    "e": 6
}];

var fixedData = data.map(function(d){
  return d3.entries(d);
});
```

Second, you want to make multiple pie charts where your outer array is a chart and your inner array is your slices.  This is great place to use a [nested selection](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).  The outer selection is a `g` element for each pie chart.  Inside this selection is the `g` element for each arc and label:

```
// create a g for each pie chart
var p = svg.selectAll(".pie")
  .data(fixedData)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "pie")
  .attr("transform",function(d,i){
    return "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + ((radius * i * 2) + radius) + ")"; //<-- place the g down the page
  });

// create an arc for each slice
var g = p.selectAll(".arc") //<-- this is a nested selection
  .data(function(d){
    return pie(d); //<-- d here is each element of the outer array
  })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");
```

---

Let's put these two ideas together with some working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.arc text {
  font: 15px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data = [{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
},{
    "a": 4,
    "d": 5,
    "e": 6
},{
    "d": 4,
    "f": 5,
    "b": 6
}];

var fixedData = data.map(function(d){
  return d3.entries(d);
});

var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) / data.length;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);
    
var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius / 2)
    .innerRadius(radius / 2);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var p = svg.selectAll(".pie")
  .data(fixedData)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "pie")
  .attr("transform",function(d,i){
    return "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + ((radius * i * 2) + radius) + ")";
  });
  
var g = p.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(function(d){
    return pie(d);
  })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.key); });

g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.data.key; });

</script>
```

Comment: A perfect explanation! Thank you so much! I am going to try this now and let you know the result!